# Show f is differentiable a x=0

Tags: functions, derivatives

here is the exercise : $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $-x^2 \leq f(x) \leq x^2$, for $x \in [-1,1]$; Show $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$

I don't have any idea to start. Could you help me ?

Thank you,

Comment: Well, first of all, what do you think the derivative would be at $x = 0$?  What would $f(x+\Delta x)$ look like in that case, for small $\Delta x$?

Comment: is it stated that $f$ is continuous?

Answer (score 1):

Show by definition,

$-0^2\le f(0)\le 0^2\Rightarrow f(0)=0$

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(h+0)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)}{h}$$

$$-h^2\le f(h)\le h^2\Rightarrow -h\le f(h)/h\le h$$
Apply Sandwich theorem to prove the limit exits.